# Custom generalized VHD is struck in activation key prompt in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have hyper-v VHD uploaded to azure by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed#upload-the-vm-vhd-to-your-storage-account).

VHD image is generalized before uploading to azure. after uploading, trying to create a VM using the uploaded VHD image and VM is not completing the provision after timeout. looking at Boot Diagnosis of the VM the VM is stuck in product key entering prompt.

[image].

The following error is logged:

```
New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'OS Provisioning for VM 'PSTACBUI'
did not finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish provisioning successfully. Please check provisioning
state later. Also, make sure the image has been properly prepared (generalized).
 * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/
 * Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/ '
ErrorCode: OSProvisioningTimedOut
ErrorMessage: OS Provisioning for VM 'PSTACBUI' did not finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish
provisioning successfully. Please check provisioning state later. Also, make sure the image has been properly prepared
(generalized).
 * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/
 * Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/
StartTime: 2/2/2018 11:04:08 PM
EndTime: 2/2/2018 11:50:59 PM
OperationID: 0a4f1ac8-9274-4fa8-b396-71c8eb690653
Status: Failed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName tacoud -Location $location
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

How I can skip product activation prompt for multiple VM deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally happens when the VHD is either not properly generalized (missing a step) or if it is turned back on prior to being uploaded to Azure.

Make sure you select each of the steps during the generalization process:

[image]

Then make sure that the VM is not turned back on again prior to uploading to Azure.

Also check this link to ensure you get all the proper pre-sysprep steps correct:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image